# How do I set up access to a DFS location using its UNC through a virtual directory in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis-10, unc, virtual-directory

I have inherited this old WebForms site that I am attempting to migrate to Windows Server 2022 on VMWare because the server it is currently running on is being retired.

The web site has links to a bunch of documents which I can get working if I set up a virtual directory so long as the documents are on the same machine as the web site. However, this is not what I want. We have a corporate domain with a DFS where the documents live that I am trying to access, unsuccessfully.

I am using Specific User Authentication with a domain user account that has permissions to access the location in question granted but when I click one of the links I get an error page with the following information.

> Config Error     Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient
> permissions
>
> Config File      \?\UNC\Servername.Domain.com\SomeFolder\web.config

What exactly is going on here and how do I get this working?

The web site is running in the DefaultAppPool using ApplicationPoolIdentity and Anonymous Authentication.

Does this mean that the user account I am using for the Specific User Authentication needs to have access to the web.config file on the machine that is hosting the documents I am trying to access?

Do I need to change the user of DefaultAppPool from ApplicationPoolIdentity to something else?
Should I be using pass-through authentication instead of specific user?

Also, in the source code, which is written in VB.NET, the original developer has a function that returns a `Generic.List(Of Document)` where `Document` is a simple class with a few properties, one of which being the URL for the document. The function, stripped of much of the irrelevant code looks something like:

```
Public Shared Function GetDocumentByType(ByVal DocumentType As String, ByVal SearchTxt As String) As Generic.List(Of Document)

    Dim fs As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
    Dim FileLoc As String
    Dim FileUrl As String
    Dim docList as New Generic.List(Of Document)()

    Select Case DocumentType
        Case "Some Type"
            FileLoc = "C:\SomePath\SomeOtherPath"
            FileUrl = "/VirtualDirectory/SomeOtherPath"
        ' Bunch of other cases here
        Case Else
            Return Nothing
    End Select

    Try
        fs = FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(FileLoc)
        For Each f1 As String in fs
            If InStr(f1, SearchTxt) Then
                FileName = Right$(f1, (Len(f1) + 1 - InStr(f1, SearchTxt)))
                NextDocument = New Document(DocumentType, FileUrl & FileName)
                list.Add(NextDocument)
            End If
    Catch e As Exception
        'Exception code here
    End Try

    Return docList

End Function
```

Which iterates through the files in `FileLoc` for a given `DocumentType` looking for files with `SearchTxt` in their names and adding a new `Document` for each of them to the returned `List(Of Document)`. The `FileUrl` is the virtual directory which resides on the same machine, and the `FileLoc` is the Physical Path which is also on the same machine. In the example of the above code the virtual directory would be pointing to "C:\SomePath" Now what I would like to know is, is this the best way of going about this, and if I get access to the DFS then can I just use the UNC for `FileLoc` and use `FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(FileLoc)` ?

Comment: You will have to open a support ticket to work with Microsoft support team to dig deeper. In short, not all DFS solutions equal, and some does have problems.

Comment: Based on what I have said am I doing anything glaringly wrong?

Comment: Is web server on domain? You can either setup that vitural folder, or you can simple create a non domain user on both web server and that other server, and use that to get at the files. So, a virtual folder not necessary required here. So, create a new user on the web server and same user on the other server. (hence non domain user - same name and password on the 2 servers). Use that for the app-pool, and thus without a virtual folder code behind should have little issue(s) reading and using those files.

Comment: It is on a domain. I have tried many configurations and the closest I can get, where I am getting a reasonable error that states the user doesn't have permissions (although they actually do) is to have it running with specific user authentication, have the app pool identity set to that same user, and have NTFS permissions to the folders in question granted to that user. But I am still not able to access the files. I have had a suggestion to change it back to the standard ApplicationPoolIdentity and grant permissions to the host machine instead of a user or group, but I can't do that. cont...

Comment: ... unfortunately, the company who provides our servers has given us a web interface to grant permissions to users and groups, but you can't select a machine the way you can if you use the security tab on a folder in the DFS and change "Object Type" to include "Computers" along with users and groups, etc.

Comment: As noted, you can create a non domain user on both computers, and that will work - a bit of a kluge, but a workaround for the time being. However, if you have the app pool running as that one user (even domain) with permissions to the other server, then this should work - but only work for code behind - not a virtual folder, but then again, I don't think you care nor it matters. So that non domain user must have same name (logon) and same password on both computers. However, since you don't have direct admin rights on both servers? Then try setting the app-pool to run as the domain user.

Comment: I would logon using that domain user you created, and double check you can use the files on that 2nd server. (do you have more then one app-pool running then? - if yes, then make sure you set them all to use the domain user that you are 100% sure works and can use files on that other server. This in theory only going to work for codebehind, and not necessary a virtual folder (which I don't think you using).

Comment: I don't have any access to the computer that has the files on it, it is a file share on a DFS which I am using a UNC path to connect to. The user account I am using is one provided by our IT provider, it is an admin account that I use to install and remove software on my machine (things are locked down tight, we need to provide credentials just to delete an item from the desktop) and to log onto the Windows Server 2022 instance I am using to host this web site. So I can't create users on both computers. I can get access to the files through the code-behind, but I am using virtual directories.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com for further guidance.